# Postfix unsupported dictionary type: mysql

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-16.04

Basically I follow this tutorial:
https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql

My problems strated with first test Postfix.

**postconf -m**

```
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf: file is owned or writable by non-root users -- skipping this file
btree
cidr
environ
fail
hash
inline
internal
memcache
nis
pipemap
proxy
randmap
regexp
socketmap
static
tcp
texthash
unionmap
unix
```

It's look like i forgot install postfix-mysql but when i try again install  i get:

```
postfix-mysql is already the newest version (3.1.0-3).
```

**postmap -q example.com mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf**

```
postmap: warning: /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf: file is owned or writable by non-root users -- skipping this file
postmap: fatal: unsupported dictionary type: mysql
```

All files .cf look like in tutorial. For mysql-* config files i set owner and group "postfix".

Any idea?

Edit:

In my case i have installed postfix-mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Ok after many hours spending time on this issue i finally found resolve:

Postfix trying read file :`/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf` and can't, becouse have wrong permissions. I set new owners and modification permission resolve my problem.

```
chown root.root /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf
chmod 640 /etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf
```

Maybe this answer will help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

As said in one of the other answers, modifying `/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf` this way:

```
# Postfix dynamic maps configuration file.
#
#type   location of .so file            open function   (mkmap func)
#====   ================================    =============   ============
tcp /usr/lib/postfix/dict_tcp.so        dict_tcp_open   
sqlite  /usr/lib/postfix/dict_sqlite.so     dict_sqlite_open    
#mysql  /usr/lib/postfix/dict_mysql.so      dict_mysql_open 
mysql   /usr/lib/postfix/postfix-mysql.so   dict_mysql_open
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/postfix/dynamicmaps.cf`
Add absolute path to `postfix-mysql.so`
In my case, this path is `/usr/lib/postfix/postfix-mysql.so`